# Issue when trying to use CSS transitions with jQuery Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I've replicated the fluid/responsive mode of Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html but with the addition of animating the width of the clicked element using "transition: width 0.3s". This does work, however it disables the 'reLayout' animation of which I'm triggering on 'transitionend'.

I'm thinking that one is overriding / conflicting with the other. Has anyone had similar issues or know a way around this? I've tried setting 'animationEngine : 'jquery', and this does resolve the issue, but it looks terrible - browser re-paining issues!?

Thanks for any help!

And here's a live demo...

http://www.voyced.com/isotope-test/

If you disable the css property "transition: width 0.3s" in the developer tools the 'reLayout' animation works again.

Comment: It would help if you shared a jsfiddle or some demo code you are working with.

Comment: indeed http://www.voyced.com/isotope-test/

Answer (score 0):

Issue a `$(window).resize()` after you animate the item.

or

```
$container.isotope('reLayout', function() {
   $(window).resize();
 });
```

Comment: I do the isotope equivalent: $container.isotope('reLayout'). They do re-position themselves, but without the animation.

Comment: Did you try the `$(window).resize()` ?  I've run it in the chrome console and it works fine on your site.  Try putting it after the relayout call.

Comment: Yep. Just pushed that change live. Testing in latest Chrome and Firefox and issue is still there.

Comment: Both the width of the clicked box should animate, and the position of all the other boxes. At the moment they just move suddenly.

Comment: Try it in the callback for the reload..  When I call window reload in chrome's console it does work. Other than that I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Do you mean resize? Can you provide the full function code you are writing. Thanks.